# Additive Blending in three.js

Tags: three.js

When dealing with particles in three.js and using Additive blending I find that the resulting particle system is visible even when there is an object, or objects for that matter, between it and the camera.

Is there a way to make sure that the particles stop being visible when there is an object obstructing them?

Comment: You first need to figure out why that is happening. If you can't do that, then post a simple, live example to demonstrate the problem (not your entire project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and it turned out that the normals of the obstruction's faces were not being calculated correctly. Once I corrected their calculation, the faces obstructed the objects behind them as one would expect.

Comment: @Zuks It depends on what shape you're rendering. In my case, I was creating a custom geometry and so the normal calculation took place in `new Face3(..., /* normal calculation */)`.